# How to load billions of records easily in handsontable in sinatra using mongo?

Tags: ruby, ajax, mongodb, sinatra, handsontable

I used **handsontable** to load thousand of records. When i load page, it will **take lots of time** to load. So, my question is: Is there any **buffer functionality** to buffer some data once then some other while scroll?
I am trying to load "100" data while first time refresh. Then while scroll, it will fetch another "100" records. But it will not work. Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have got so far. Show us what does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called *infinite scroll* and handsontable seems to have all the tools needed to build support for it. Read their documentation's [Function datasources](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.24.1/tutorial-data-sources.html#page-property-schema) section. You will need to implement the *lazy loader* yourself though.

The feature [has been requested](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/607) couple of years ago, but has not been implemented yet. Some have written [plugins with a support](https://gist.github.com/marcsch/c8317978e1d26bf049bb).

Alternatively, implement it in the form of *pagination*. Handsontable already [has the support](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.24.1/demo-paginating.html). When user clicks on the other page link, load it through AJAX and feed it back to Handsontable. The link above has an example, just add your ajax call.

Comment: @Tech consider selecting the answer to mark your question closed.